# Perl6 installed modules

Tags: raku

Is there any command in the Perl6 Rakudo distribution which lists all the installed modules on the system?

I tried the following command:

```
 p6doc NativeCall
```

and get the following error :

```
===SORRY!===
Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable)
```

but when I write a p6 file which contains :

```
use  NativeCall;
```

it compiles with no problem.

How can I browse for such a Perl 6 module (like perldoc for Perl 5) and how can I list all the installed Perl 6 modules?

Comment: p6doc NativeCall provide this message on Windows :===SORRY!=== Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable) even its installed

Comment: sorry its  NativeCall but i still get the same error :(

Answer (score 9):

## The module manager is `zef`, not `p6doc`

`p6doc ...` is meant for managing (searching/displaying) *documentation* not for managing modules.

`zef` should already be installed on your system. If not, install it from [its github repo](https://github.com/ugexe/zef).

The error message you got from `p6doc` suggests something is borked in your installation. I think it's most likely something not worth chasing for another month so I suggest you ignore it for a month, make sure you're running an up-to-date Perl 6 distribution (eg the latest Rakudo Star), and then, if it's still around, consider speaking up about it on #perl6 and mentioning [this closed bug report](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/138#issuecomment-143784827).

Hth.

Answer (score 9):

zef is your (best) friend in Perl6 universe.

```
zef --help
```

will give you any information you have ever wish aboutZef and how to use it and therefore any information about any installed modules.

```
zef list --installed
```

If you are looking  for a specific module, you can use:

```
zef search module
```

in the list returned, you'll see in the first lines:

```
Zef::Repository::LocalCache... Module
...
```

which gives you a list of installed modules related to your question.